# vertically middle Image in a div [There is more space in bottom than top]

Tags: html, css

As you can see [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62r611m0/1/) image is not vertically align proper. There is more space between the lower borders than uppers.
I am using

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
```

Comment: Like Niza answered. You need to apply vertical-align middle to the img. Not to the container.

Comment: You need to apply to both, otherwise it's not getting in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't read a question, but I think you want to solve it. Try this:

```
.myimage {
   border: 1px solid black;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block; margin: auto;` to the image. https://jsfiddle.net/Lxf818d7/

(Not sure if you need it inline though; would have to investigate further.)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
.mydiv {
   width: 300px;
   height:auto;
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
   padding:5px 0px;
}

.myimage {
   border: 1px solid black;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/h5o01yk8/)